# Eigen Map returns partly garbage after deleting original data

Tags: c++, eigen, eigen3

I'm trying to use `Eigen::Map` to convert a pointer to raw data to a matrix and then free the original data, but keep getting some weird results as if the data in the `Eigen::Map` itself is deleted. I thought `Eigen::Map` performed a deep copy, though maybe this only happens after you convert the `Eigen::Map` to a matrix?

Here is some test code:

```
#include <Eigen/Dense>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    double* data = new double[4]; 
    data[0] = 1; 
    data[1] = 2; 
    data[2] = 3; 
    data[3] = 4; 

    Eigen::Map<Eigen::Matrix<double, 2, 2, Eigen::RowMajor>> M(data);
    Eigen::Matrix<double, 2, 2, Eigen::RowMajor> N = M.matrix();    
    std::cout << M << std::endl; 
    std::cout << N << std::endl; 
    delete[] data;  
    std::cout << M << std::endl;
    std::cout << N << std::endl; 
  
    return 0; 
}
```

Which results in this for me:

```
1 2
3 4
1 2
3 4
           0 4.67506e-310
           3            4
1 2
3 4
```

Is there something I'm doing wrong to get this behaviour from M in my example? Or are you supposed to convert it to N, like I've done? And is this inefficient, or does Eigen handle the assignment N = M.matrix() in some smart way?

Comment: `Eigen::Map` does not copy, where did you get that information?

Comment: I think I misunderstood the documentation... So if I understand this correctly, Eigen::Map doesn't copy until you explicitly convert it to a matrix?

Comment: That's right, Eigen::Map "views" existing memory without deep copying it. The mapped memory must outlive the Map. You can make a copy by assigning the Map to an Eigen::Matrix.